# Python Asyncio subprocess never finishes

Tags: python, python-asyncio

i have a simple python program that I'm using to test asyncio with subprocesses:

```
import sys, time
for x in range(100):
    print("processing (%s/100)    " % x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
print("enjoy")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Running this on the command line produces the desired results.

However, when called from asyncio, it never finishes

```
process = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
    *["python", "program.py"],
    stdout=async_subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=async_subprocess.STDOUT,
    cwd=working_dir
)

# this never finishes
yield from process.communicate()
```

`ps ax` shows this process is `<defunct>`, not sure what that means

Comment: What you wrote is not valid python code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect your issue is just related to how you're calling  `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` and `process.communiate()`. This complete example works fine for me:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import subprocess

@asyncio.coroutine
def do_work():
    process = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *["python", "program.py"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )

    stdout, _= yield from process.communicate()
    print(stdout)

if __name__  == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(do_work())
```

You have to place code that uses `yield from` inside of a `asyncio.coroutine`, and then call it inside an event loop (using `loop.run_until_complete`), for it to behave the way you want it to.