# asynchronous subprocess using flask-aiohttp

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I'm using a [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) web server to provide an interface to a time-consuming calculation. To increase performance, I want to

1. start the calculation as a [new subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) to be able to use multiple CPU cores for multiple concurrent calculations
2. let the calculations run asynchronously using [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html)

To call `asyncio` coroutines from Flask I started using [`flask-aiohttp`](http://flask-aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/coroutine.html), which is working nicely for simple delay tasks as shown in the examples.
However, I fail to call the asynchronous subprocess from inside Flask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.aiohttp import AioHTTP, async

import asyncio
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE

CALC_SCRIPT = './calc'

app = Flask(__name__)
aio = AioHTTP(app)

@app.route('/calc/<int:n>')
@async
def calc(n):
    print('calc({}) called'.format(n))
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(CALC_SCRIPT, str(n),
                                            stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    print('create... ', end='')
    process = yield from create
    print('process created. {!r}, type={}'.format(process,
                                                  type(process)))
    yield from process.wait()
    print('process finished.')

    # yields (stdout, stderr)
    result = '\n'.join(ch.decode().rstrip() for ch in
                        (yield from process.communicate()) if ch)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aio.run(app, debug=True)
```

The process is being created, but never returns:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/calc/5
calc(5) called
creating... process created. <Process 5647>,
    type=<class 'asyncio.subprocess.Process'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sure that you have thought through this already, but what does *CALC_SCRIPT* do? Are you testing with a simple function, like a factorial or something?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541192/python-asyncio-subprocess-never-finishes

Comment: Yes, `CALC_SCRIPT` is a [slow fibonacci script](https://gitlab.com/snippets/11746) for testing purposes. I've stumbled over that question you've linked to, but my [standalone version](https://gitlab.com/snippets/11748) is working well.

Comment: Does `process.wait()` cause the computation to go through? Can you create an `asyncio.couroutine` outside of the view function, and then call on it in a similar way as you do in the standalone version, within the view function?

Answer (score 2):

Reason: running asyncio subprocesses from sub-threads has limits, see asyncio docs [Subprocess and threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-and-threads).

Detail: with `debug=True`, Flask-aiohttp handle requests in a sub-thread started by Werkzeug's `run_with_reloader`. Turn debug off and your code runs correctly.

Alternatively according to the docs above, Flask-aiohttp should add a call to `asyncio.get_child_watcher()` right before calling `run_with_reloader`. With this call, your code runs even with `debug=True`.